# Django Add related_name error on AbstractUser Custom model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

Django shows this error when migrating

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
accounts.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accounts.CustomUser.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.
accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'accounts.CustomUser.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'accounts.CustomUser.user_permissions'.
```

It is suggesting to add `related_name` but I have not user any ForeignKey Field in my model, My model is inheriting from the AbstractUser

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'CUSTOMER'),
        (2, 'AGENT'),
        (3, 'SUPERVISOR'),
    )
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Have you mentioned `AUTH_USER_MODEL`  in `settings.py`?

Comment: @JPG no I haven't

Answer (score 2):

Add `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py` for your custom user model as

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.CustomUser'
```