# Django custom-user error: HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'custom_auth.CustomUser.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, registration

I need help. I'm creating an registration/login app in Django and I'm having some trouble making migrations of my CustomUser class. Below is the error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'custom_auth.CustomUser.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'custom_auth.CustomUser.groups'.
custom_auth.CustomUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'custom_auth.CustomUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
```

I tried adding a related name as was a suggestion to a similar question here, but it still throws the same error when I makemigrations.

The code for my models.py is as below:

```
# custom_auth/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    # Add a related_name to the user_permissions field
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='auth.Permission',
        related_name='custom_users',
        blank=True,
    )
```

Comment: did you set your auth user model?

Answer (score 1):

you have to override the groups and give it a related_name

```
custom_groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        related_name='custom_users',
        blank=True,
    )
```

add this to your custom user model

Comment: Thank you, I added this together with the AUTH_USER_MODEL suggested by @martin and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226143/django-add-related-name-error-on-abstractuser-custom-model), if you specify your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.py, the clash should disappear.

```py
# settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_auth.CustomUser'
```

Comment: Yes, it worked after adding this

Comment: Glad it helped Kelvin! Please vote up the answer if you think others could find it useful